# Unable to install juju-gui locally?

Tags: juju

I'm attempting to setup juju-gui in a VM running Ubuntu 13.10 x64 Server.
I intend to see if it's possible to deploy an openstack "all in one" node, using this method in that particular VM.

I've installed and bootstrapped juju in a local environment :

```
sudo apt-get install juju-core
sudo apt-get install juju-local
juju switch local
sudo juju bootstrap
```

Next I've executed the following :

```
juju deploy juju-gui
juju expose juju-gui
watch juju status
```

I was expecting to see juju-gui open up some ports and become available via a web-browser but nothing like that happened - why? how do I fix that? I believe I've managed to follow the deployment guides to the letter?

Are there any detailed walkthroughs regarding deploying openstack on 13.10, using juju?

Comment: I have heard a few people say you need to restart if you have never used LXC on that machine before. I haven't experienced this personally, so it could all be mythology, but you might give it a try and report back if that does it...

Answer (score 4):

The last thing you did "juju watch status" is a bit off.  It should call the "watch" command on "juju status", i.e

```
watch juju status
```

(That just runs juju status periodically and shows the results.)

After a while, the juju-gui portion of the status output will show the agent-state as "started" and display a public IP address.

At that point you can open your browser and go to the IP address.  You'll be prompted for a password, which is the 'admin-secret' found in your `~/.juju/environments.yaml` under the "local" section.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi :) Thanks for pointing my obvious error out. How long does it take to have this up and running? Is there some way to determine progress?

Comment: @Maciek The spin-up time is highly dependant on the performance of the machine as the download size of the charm is rather small. The only real way to determine the status of the setup is to tail the GUI charms logs (see the answer below from Rick) and know where in the setup that log corresponds to.

Answer (score 3):

Expose doesn't do anything in the local provider. There are no firewalls rules in place like other providers such as ec2. Once you deploy the juju-gui and it's started, you should be able to visit it via the ip address for the lxc machine that juju status shows you.

It is available on port 80 and 443.

If it did not come up to "started" state then please ssh to that machine and grab the log for the unit in `/var/log/juju/unit-*` and let us know.

Comment: It does not come up for me, too: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7149890/

Comment: onrea that it shows pending means it's not completed installing. It should either get to running or to an error state. You can follow along by tailing the unit log for the service. If you can't get it running hop into #juju-gui on Freenode and we'll be happy to help debug what the issue is.